# Why won't my preloader disappear and show my page when it loads? And why does it only spin twice?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a student who is pretty new to coding, and I'm trying to get my preloader to disappear and show my webpage. However, the spinner rotates twice and then freezes. It won't show my actual webpage once the page is loaded either.

HTML:

```html
<div class="preloader">
   <img src="./Images/loading.png">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.minjs"></script>
<script src="js/template.js"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: fit-content;
}
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 100000;
    background-color: #FFA800;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
.preloader img {
    animation: spin 3s ease;
    width: 150px;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    50% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(720deg)}
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

JS:

```js
function fade(){
    $(preloader).fadeOut(slow);
    setTimeout(fade, 1000);
    setTimeout(fade, 3000);
}
```

I wasn't sure what to try, I had followed the instructions of a previous assignment from my class and it still wasn't working.

Comment: use infinite in animation. eg.  animation: mymove 5s infinite; Refer https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation.php

Answer (score 1):

it's a minor code fixing, please check below working fiddle, you gave `preload` and `slow` as variables, but in your snippet, those are not declared, and on the initial call, your `fade()` function was not triggering,

[function calling](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/call-function-javascript) read here about calling functions in JS,

[fading](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_fade.asp) read here is more about fading of jquery

```js
function fade(){
    $('.preloader').fadeOut('slow');
    setTimeout(fade, 1000);
    setTimeout(fade, 3000);
}

fade()
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: fit-content;
}
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 100000;
    background-color: #FFA800;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;`
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
.preloader img {
    animation: spin 3s ease;
    width: 150px;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    50% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(720deg)}
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    from {opacity: 1;}
    to {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="preloader">
  <img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/168/200/300.jpg?hmac=ILU5dddz6ohoQEq3_1fmoy2wEFfM1V1JfjLX_JsbOz0" />
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```